# c# convert byte array to float and divide them by value

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, converters

I've a fallowing code which receives byte and probably has to perform convert to float and represent its converted values :

```
 public float DecodeFloat(byte[] data)
    {
        float x = data[3]|data[2]<<8|data[1]<<16|data[0]<<24;
        return x;
    }

     // receive thread 
  private  void ReceiveData() 
    {
        int count=0;

       IPEndPoint remoteIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.2.213"), port);
       client = new UdpClient(remoteIP);
        while (true) 
        {
           try 
            {
                IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                byte[] data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);

                Vector3 vec,rot;
                float x= DecodeFloat (data);
                float y= DecodeFloat (data + 4);
                float z= DecodeFloat (data + 8);
                float alpha= DecodeFloat (data + 12);
                float theta= DecodeFloat (data +16);
                float phi= DecodeFloat (data+20);

                vec.Set(x,y,z);
                rot.Set (alpha,theta,phi);


                print(">> " + x.ToString() + ", "+ y.ToString() + ", "+ z.ToString() + ", "
                    + alpha.ToString() + ", "+ theta.ToString() + ", "+ phi.ToString());

                // latest UDPpacket
                lastReceivedUDPPacket=x.ToString()+" Packet#: "+count.ToString();
                count = count+1;



            }
```

Is there anyone to put me in the right way, please?

Comment: Please describe inputs, wanted outputs, what is currently happening and what should be happening. As it currently stands, this is not a question that can be answered.

Comment: @Oded oh, I don't know - IMO the "problem" is fairly obvious from the code.

Comment: @Marc - Sure, the `DecodeFloat` function shouts "wrong" to me too, but I am trying to help the OP with how to formulate a good question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given 4 bytes, you would normally only "shift" (`<<`) if it is integer data. The code in the question basically *reads* the data as an `int` (via "shift"), then casts the `int` to a `float`. Which is almost certainly not what was intended.

Since you want to interpret it as `float`, you should probably use:

```
float val = BitConverter.ToSingle(data, offset);
```

where offset is the 0, 4, 8, 12 etc shown in your `data + 4`, `data + 8`, etc. This treats the 4 bytes (relative to `offset`) as raw IEEE 754 floating point data. For example:

```
float x= BitConverter.ToSingle(data, 0);
float y= BitConverter.ToSingle(data, 4);
float z= BitConverter.ToSingle(data, 8);
float alpha= BitConverter.ToSingle(data, 12);
float theta= BitConverter.ToSingle(data, 16);
float phi= BitConverter.ToSingle(data, 20);
```

Note that this makes assumptions about "endianness" - see `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`.

---

Edit: from comments, it sounds like the data is other-endian; try:

```
public static float ReadSingleBigEndian(byte[] data, int offset)
{
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    {
        byte tmp = data[offset];
        data[offset] = data[offset + 3];
        data[offset + 3] = tmp;
        tmp = data[offset + 1];
        data[offset + 1] = data[offset + 2];
        data[offset + 2] = tmp;
    }
    return BitConverter.ToSingle(data, offset);
}
public static float ReadSingleLittleEndian(byte[] data, int offset)
{
    if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    {
        byte tmp = data[offset];
        data[offset] = data[offset + 3];
        data[offset + 3] = tmp;
        tmp = data[offset + 1];
        data[offset + 1] = data[offset + 2];
        data[offset + 2] = tmp;
    }
    return BitConverter.ToSingle(data, offset);
}
...
float x= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, 0);
float y= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, 4);
float z= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, 8);
float alpha= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, 12);
float theta= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, 16);
float phi= ReadSingleBigEndian(data, 20);
```

If you need to optimize this massively, there are also things you can do with unsafe code to build an `int` from shifting (picking the endianness when shifting), then do an unsafe coerce to get the `int` as a `float`; for example (noting that I haven't checked endianness here - it might misbehave on a big-endian machine, but most people don't have those):

```
public static unsafe float ReadSingleBigEndian(byte[] data, int offset)
{
    int i = (data[offset++] << 24) | (data[offset++] << 16) |
            (data[offset++] << 8) | data[offset];
    return *(float*)&i;
}
public static unsafe float ReadSingleBigEndian(byte[] data, int offset)
{
    int i = (data[offset++]) | (data[offset++] << 8) |
            (data[offset++] << 16) | (data[offset] << 24);
    return *(float*)&i;
}
```

Or crazier, and CPU-safer:

```
public static float ReadSingleBigEndian(byte[] data, int offset)
{
    return ReadSingle(data, offset, false);
}
public static float ReadSingleLittleEndian(byte[] data, int offset)
{
    return ReadSingle(data, offset, true);
}
private static unsafe float ReadSingle(byte[] data, int offset,
    bool littleEndian)
{
    fixed (byte* ptr = &data[offset])
    {
        if (littleEndian != BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {   // other-endian; swap
            byte b = ptr[0];
            ptr[0] = ptr[3];
            ptr[3] = b;
            b = ptr[1];
            ptr[1] = ptr[2];
            ptr[2] = b;
        }
        return *(float*)ptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Marc, thank you very much!!! It was very helpful! Problem is solved :D

Comment: Mark, its do converting but its shows 5.832204E-42 instead of 36.000. I also tried array.reverse its shows only 0. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @user1764781 k; that means the endianness is backwards. You don't want to reverse the entire of `data` - just those 4 bytes; I'll update my answer, 2 seconds